# local variable 'price_end' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sql, error-handling, web-crawler

I ran into a little problem. Here is my code:

```
front_deeplink = ("http://www.sozi.com")

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}

Region = "turkey/istanbul"   


def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 0
    partner_ID = Yes
    location_ID = No

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect\
            (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd ="", db = "local")
    except:
        print("Keine Verbindung zum Server")
        sys.exit(0)

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("DELETE from prices_crawled where LocationID=" + str(location_ID) + " and PartnerID=" + str(partner_ID))
    connection.commit()

    while page <= max_pages:
        page += 1
        r = requests.get("http://www.zosi.com/things-to-do/" + str(Region) + "/?per_page=10&page=" + str(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "column info"})

        for item in g_data:
            Header = item.find_all("a")
            for t in set(t.get("data-product-name") for t in Header):
                Header_final = t
            price = item.find_all("div", {"class": "price"})
            Price_final = (price[0].text.strip()[8:])
            if Price_final:
                price_end = int(float(Price_final)*100*Change)
            Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
            for j in set(j.get("href") for j in Deeplink):
                Deeplink_final = (str(front_deeplink) + j)
            Language = "Englisch"


            print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "Price: " + str(price_end) + " | " + "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(partner_ID) + " | " + "LocationID: " + str(location_ID)+ " | " + "Language: " + Language)

            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO local2 (price_id, Header,  Price, Deeplink, PartnerID, LocationID, Language) \
                    VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', ['None'] + [Header_final] + [price_end] + [Deeplink_final] + [partner_ID] + [location_ID] + [Language])

            connection.commit()



    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
trade_spider(8)

Outcome:
File "C:/Users/hmattu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/grayline.com.py", line 84, in <module>
trade_spider(8)
  File "C:/Users/hmattu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/grayline.com.py", line 66, in trade_spider
    print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "Price: " + str(price_end) + " | " + "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(partner_ID) + " | " + "LocationID: " + str(location_ID)+ " | " + "Language: " + Language)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'price_end' referenced before assignment
```

The issue starts when I start the program. It opens the console, but immediately quits. It doesn't output any information either.
I'm not quite sure what's going on, if someone could help me, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: What should happen if you get to `print("Header: " ...)` but `if Price_final` was never True? Then `price_end` won't have any value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only assign a value to `price_end` if `Price_final` is something [truthy](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). A solution would be to raise an Exception yourself otherwise or assign a value that is a string which gives some information.

```
if Price_final:
    price_end = int(float(Price_final)*100*Change)
else:
    raise ValueError('No Price can be evaluated')
    #or price_end = 'No price can be evaluated'
```